# Is there a difference between "quicker" and "more quickly"

Tags: adverbs, comparatives

This is a follow up to this question: [What is the difference between "quicker" and "faster"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31732/what-is-the-difference-between-quicker-and-faster)

"Quicker" is an adverb, as are "more" (in this context) and "quickly".

So is there a difference besides preference between these?

Comment: Simply: *quicker* is the comparative form of *quick* and *more quickly* is the comparative form of *quickly*. So the question becomes: what is the difference between the adverbs *quick* and *quickly*? I don't believe there is one.

Comment: I say use "faster" and "more fastly".  ;)  +1 to @Peter Shor, though.

Comment: You can say 'A is quicker than B', but not 'A is more quickly than B'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Quicker* is the comparative of *quick*, which is an adjective; *more quickly* is the comparative of *quickly*, which is an adverb.

Informally, *quick* is also used as adverb, with the meaning of "at a fast rate, quickly." These are the examples reported by the NOAD (third edition).

> He'll find some place where he can make money quicker.
>   Get out, quick!

Comment: When I read that first sample sentence, it sounds awkward to me. The more natural form, to me, is "He'll find some place where he can make money more quickly." Is this simply preference on my part, or can I claim by-the-rules superiority over people who use "quicker" with more than a farcical and preferential basis? ;)

Comment: @music2myear _Quick_ is used as adverb only in informal contexts; it is also possible that usage is limited to specific zones.

Comment: I am usually not concerned with strict grammar, but I think the informal usage of quick as an adverb and therefore quicker as the comparative form of an adverb should not be used. Sentences can become ambiguous if their meaning is the same.

Comment: Could you please link properly. Your first sentence comes over as unsupported opinion.

Answer (score 7):

I think *quicker* is sometimes used as an adjective, but as an adverb both are used to the same effect.  From [Google's Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=quicker,more%20quickly&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it seems that *quicker* used to be more common but that *more quickly* is slightly commoner now.

[image]

Comment: This Ngram could be measuring lots of things, including the relative frequency of *quicker* used as an adjective and adverb. One would never (I hope) say: *The hand is more quickly than the eye.*

Comment: @Peter: true, but if *more quickly* is now more common than *quicker* in any sense, then *more quickly* (which can only be used as an adverb) must now be more common than *quicker* used as an adverb.

Comment: I wish you'd said *commoner* there! :)

Comment: +1 for an interesting graph. That appeals to my historical interests quite well, possibly illustrating, besides simple usage comparison, the preference for different patterns of speech over the last few centuries.

Answer (score 0):

As I know that the word 'quick' is as well an adjective and as well an adverb e.g: I am quick in observing(as an adjective) and look quick(as an adverb) so from this sentences we can understand that 'quicker and more quickly' both are correct and are used comparative degree e.g: my cousin writes more quickly/quicker than my friend.