# Usage of Quicker and more quickly

Tags: word-usage, sentence

Which of the following sentences are correct?

Calves require less medication and gain weight quicker than that those raised in consignment.

Calves require less medication and gain weight more quickly than that those raised in consignment.

Comment: See this post http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31814/is-there-a-difference-between-quicker-and-more-quickly

Comment: The second sentence is the better choice because you are saying "how" the calves gain weight, it's not "slower" nor "shorter" e.g "They gain weight slower/shorter than ..."  But "The calves gain weight in a shorter space/period of time" = *more quickly*. The opposite would be: "Calves gain weight more slowly than...."

Comment: No , I got the answer . Here we are not comparing the speed ...instead the two groups of calves are being compared.on

Comment: But you're comparing the amount of time it takes for the calves in both groups to increase their weight. My example with "shorter (adj) space of time" was illustrative, it means the same as "quickly" i.e "gain weight more quickly"

Comment: On a different note, I'm confused by the "that those" in both sentences. It seems it should be either "...than that raised in consignment" if you're talking about one animal, or "...than those raised in consignment" if you're talking about multiple animals.

Answer (score 0):

Both the sentences explain the same situation. One takes the help of 'quick', an adjective and the other 'quickly', an adverb. There is the sense of comparison between the two groups. And degree of comparison can well be expressed with the help of either adjective or adverb.

I am more inclined to consider 'quick', in the first sentence as a predicative adjective, though 'quick' has adverbial use as in the sentence:

Get rich quick.

So first group of calves gains quicker weight.

2) In the 2nd. Sentence 'quickly' is an adverb and it also states exactly the same like the earlier sentence. Since writer wants to retain quickly he takes the help of 'more' to introduce the sense of comparison.
However, we have severe reservation about the use of that-rather this 'that' should be removed. Only "those" can easily express the function of pronoun replacing calves and avoidance of grammatical error.

## Now,let us view the sentences in another light. QUICKLY-(Adv.positive degree)

QUICKER (its comparative degree. So is the form!!!)
QUICKEST (its superlative form!)
In one the root 'quickly' is retained and in the other its transformation is used. THE DIFFERENCE IS ONLY THIS FAR, AND NO FURTHER!!

However,in no case we are not in favour of 'that' to be used.